# Generating a random sequence in Python

Tags: python, random, sequence

I want to generate a sequence that contains an integer (say x) 'm' times and another integer (say y) 'n' times. How do I do this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: google python random   and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Here are some guidelines: Please do not ask us to do this for you without showing any efforts or any code attempts. Note that Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service, at least show your efforts and attempts in making this. Please read the How to ask and the on topic questions section of Stackoverflow. Asking low quality questions like this will end up getting downvoted or the question can be closed or deleted. Regards, Anonymouse

Comment: Seems like you need to lookup:
- Generating random numbers
- Creating a list from a single value replicated (probably some sort of range function)
- Concatenating two lists together

Answer (score 2):

To get random values you can pass the list of `m` and `n` numbers into [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) with a `k` value equal to the total.

```
import random

x = 'X'
m = 3

y = 'Y'
n = 5

for i in range(5):
    print(random.sample([x]*m + [y]*n, k=m+n))
```

Prints:

```
['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']
['Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X']
['Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']
['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X']
['X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X']
```

If you are on Python 3.9, you can now pass a `counts` argument making things a little simple:

```
random.sample([x, y], counts=[m,n] k=m+n)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could first define the set of values, and then choose indices based on `random.randrange()`:

```
items = [*(x,)*n, *(y,)*m]
seq = [items.pop(random.randrange(0, len(items))) for i in range(m+n)]
```

`pop()` makes sure that the list gets consumed at each selection.